# i have an array with 8 values in it i want to print 4 in each row dynamically

Tags: php, arrays

this is the array

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [cat_count] => 1 
        ) 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [cat_count] => 0 
        ) 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [cat_count] => 0 
        ) 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [cat_count] => 1 
        ) 
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [cat_count] => 0 
        ) 
    ) 
    [5] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [cat_count] => 1 
        ) 
    ) 
    [6] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [cat_count] => 1 
        ) 
    ) 
    [7] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [cat_count] => 0 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - You need to show us what you've tried, the expected result and what result you're currently getting. You should also include what your actual issue is, not just "I want", which suggests that SO is a free coding service, which it isn't.

Comment: Hint: array_chunk($array, 4); :D

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't given very much information about your problem, it's not easy to give a 'correct' answer. But i think you can go with this:

x = your array

```
foreach(array_chunk($x, 4) AS $chunk){
    foreach($chunk AS $value){
        echo $value->catcount.' - ';
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

thx to @smartpal for the array_chunk idea